# Most efficient way to get first value that startswith of large list

Tags: python, list, lambda, startswith

I have a very large list with over a 100M strings. An example of that list look as follows:

```
l = ['1,1,5.8067',
     '1,2,4.9700',
     '2,2,3.9623',
     '2,3,1.9438',
     '2,7,1.0645', 
     '3,3,8.9331',
     '3,5,2.6772',
     '3,7,3.8107',
     '3,9,7.1008']
```

I would like to get the first string that starts with e.g. '3'.

To do so, I have used a lambda iterator followed by next() to get the first item:

```
next(filter(lambda i: i.startswith('3,'), l))
```

```
Out[1]: '3,3,8.9331'
```

Considering the size of the list, this strategy unfortunately still takes relatively much time for a process I have to do over and over again. I was wondering if someone could come up with an even faster, more efficient approach. I am open for alternative strategies.

Comment: Needs a more precise specification. What do your strings look like in general?

Comment: also, is the list sorted always?

Comment: @Deep: No the list is not sorted, so ```bisect_left``` won't work sadly

Comment: @superbrain The strings look almost identical to the example, but here is the head of the real list:
```['301\t301\t51.806763\n',
 '301\t302\t46.970094\n',
 '301\t303\t39.962393\n',
 '301\t304\t18.943836\n',
 '301\t305\t11.064584\n',
 '301\t306\t4.751911\n',
...
```

Comment: @superbrain is the question clear? If not let me know what's unlcear

Comment: Why don't you sort it first?

Comment: If you first sort, and then do ```next()```, you'll of course get a different first element compared to unsorted

Comment: So do they always start with a number followed by the same separator (comma or tab), and the queries are always looking for a full number? How many different first numbers are there?

Comment: @pr94 Why would sorting get you a different first element?

Comment: Yes the queries are always numbers and always separated by tab (just used comma in the example for clarity)

Comment: If you've to do this over and over again, maybe you can make different sub lists.. which would require you to have control while appending element into list.. which I don't know whether you have or not... if list doesn't changes in between multiple calls you're  making... it *might* be benificial to first sort the list.

Comment: @superbrain: Sorting will lexicographically sort the data, the original list is not sorted in this way. So if you do so, the first item is no longer the first item of the original list

Comment: @pr94 But the first *matching* item should still be the same. No? Please provide an example where that fails.

Comment: @superbrain after sorting AND ```startswith``` on ```'301\t'``` the first item of the list is this ```'301\t10072\t1.642927\n'``` which is not the same as in the original list as I showed you a few comments earlier

Comment: Then you're probably sorting by the whole strings instead of just by the first number in each string.

Comment: I have used ```l = sorted(l)```, can I do it differently?

Comment: Yes, like I said, by first number in each string. So for example `l.sort(key=lambda s: s[:s.find('\t')])`.

Comment: Got it, thanks! And then followed by ```bisect_left``` would be your suggestion?

Comment: Possibly. But the dictionary answer is probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no way of testing it myself but it is possible that if you will join all the strings with a char that is not in any of the string:

```py
concat_list = '$'.join(l)
```

And now use a simple `.find('$3,')`, it would be faster. It might happen if all the strings are relatively short. Since now all the string is in one place in memory.

---

If the amount of unique letters in the text is small you can use `Abrahamson-Kosaraju` method and het time complexity of practically `O(n)`

---

Another approach is to use joblib, create `n` threads when the `i`'th thread is checking the `i + k * n`, when one is finding the pattern it stops the others. So the time complexity is `O(naive algorithm / n)`.

Comment: I am going to try your solution and let you know how it performs. Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: The time complexity of the OP's solution is already *O(n)*, which the solutions in this answer do not actually improve.

Comment: @blhsing Complexity class is the same, but this is likely **vastly** faster due to simple low-level C instead of bulky Python.

Comment: "**vastly**" is indeed correct, this method seems to be way faster!

Comment: @blhsing Wrote a little test, seems about 30 times faster (0.2 seconds vs 6 seconds): https://repl.it/repls/WheatDelectableCircles#main.py

Comment: Yes, this solution is definitely the fastest. It is also more than fast enough for my application. Many thanks!

Comment: Slight bug: The first item (`l[0]`) will not be prefixed with your separator, so it won't be found.

Comment: @pr94 Hmm, blhsing's should be faster. Is it not?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll add an extra line to avoid that bug

Comment: @superbrain no it's not, to generate ```d``` takes very long! Even interrupted my kernel, because my laptop overheated.

Comment: @pr94 Ok :-). That's actually why I earlier said it's *probably* better (than the sorting solution). Because of the possibility of the dict creation being problematic. Did you try blhsing's newest version `d = {s.split('\t')[0]: s for s in reversed(l)}`, though? Or only the other one?

Comment: I have tried both options, both terminated prematurely. A (minor) disadvantage of Yonlif's suggestion though, is that storing this 0.9Gb list in a string creates a ~2.4Gb string.

Comment: @pr94 Well, but those 0.9Gb aren't the whole data, right? Just the list object. Not counting all the data in the string objects, which probably cost several more Gb. After you built the huge string, you don't need those anymore. Actually... your strings like `'301\t303\t39.962393\n'` end with `\n`, so looks like you're reading this from a file like `l = list(f)` or `l = f.readlines()`. Then you should just do `concat_list = f.read()` instead (but with a better name) and use the `\n` instead of the `$`.

Comment: That's correct, I am using ```f.readlines()```. I am working on getting this function as optimal as possible. Hence, all your comments are much appreciated!

Comment: @pr94 Maybe what you should really use is NumPy or Pandas, have a 2D array or dataframe of floats. Depends on your data. Btw, you'd better always address/notify people. I only saw your last few comments because I kept the tab open and actively looked.

Comment: @superbrain yes, numpy is what is tried initially. Though it takes far longer to load this data using e.g. ```np.loadtxt``` than with ```f.readlines()```. In my experience pandas is much slower on large datasets than numpy, so didn't even bother trying that.

Answer (score 2):

Since your actual strings consist of relatively short tokens (such as `301`) after splitting the the strings by tabs, you can build a dict with each possible length of the first token as the keys so that subsequent lookups take only *O(1)* in average time complexity.

Build the dict with values of the list in reverse order so that the first value in the list that start with each distinct character will be retained in the final dict:

```
d = {s[:i + 1]: s for s in reversed(l) for i in range(len(s.split('\t')[0]))}
```

so that given:

```
l = ['301\t301\t51.806763\n', '301\t302\t46.970094\n',
     '301\t303\t39.962393\n', '301\t304\t18.943836\n',
     '301\t305\t11.064584\n', '301\t306\t4.751911\n']
```

`d['3']` will return `'301\t301\t51.806763'`.

If you only need to test each of the first tokens as a whole, rather than prefixes, you can simply make the first tokens as the keys instead:

```
d = {s.split('\t')[0]: s for s in reversed(l)}
```

so that `d['301']` will return `'301\t301\t51.806763'`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for the OP's specific input then.

Comment: Heh, now it seems a bit of overkill. This is why I asked them whether "queries are always looking for a *full* number". They replied "Yes the queries are always numbers and always separated by tab", which, while not 100% clear, sounds to me like we don't need number prefixes.

Comment: @superbrain Yes, that was my first thought, but I made the solution for varying prefixes just to be on the safe side, not realizing that you've already asked for clarification in the comments. I've updated my answer accordingly then.